# eslint is running but not showing any lint errors/warnings

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, eslintrc

I am using vscode with eslint.  The eslint console shows the following:

```
[Info  - 3:31:14 PM] ESLint server stopped.
[Info  - 3:31:14 PM] ESLint server running in node v10.2.0
[Info  - 3:31:14 PM] ESLint server is running.
[Info  - 3:31:15 PM] ESLint library loaded from: 
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/api.js
```

So eslint appears to be loading and running.  However, there is a `.eslintrc` file in my project root that has rules and vscode is not showing me any linting errors.

How do I debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to

1. install `eslint-plugin-vue`
2. add the following to settings.json in vscode

   ```
   "eslint.validate": [
       {
         "language": "vue",
         "autoFix": true
       },
       {
         "language": "html",
         "autoFix": true
       },
       {
         "language": "javascript",
         "autoFix": true
       }
   ```
3. and update .eslintrc to include

   ```
   "globals: "Vue" : true,"
   ```

   and

   ```
   "extends": [
       "eslint:recommended",
       "plugin:vue/recommended"
   ],
   ```

   in addition to

   ```
   "plugins": ["html"],
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to install an extension for VSCode to show lint errrors in the editor. Otherwise you can run eslint from the terminal to see its output. I use tslint so I don't know which extension to use but https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint might be what you're looking for.